# Intellij idea new editorconfig can be not applied

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to add new tomcat configs, but when i click on "Apply " or "Ok", nothing seems to be added, i tried to restart the Idea, but no luck.

[image: Edit Configuration]
[image: Click Apply]

Answer (score 0):

To add Run/Debug configuration you need to press plus in the top left corner. According to the screenshot you expanded "Defaults" list and changed Tomcat configuration there. In this case defaut configuration is changed and entered settings will persist in every new created configuration (using green plus).